# retieve data from database using as3

Tags: php, database, actionscript-3, flash, mysqli

I had created a database "new" using xampp localhost database had 2 tables user and score. I had an AS3 code which had 2 input textfield to insert user and score value into database tables.
Now I am trying to retrieve the inserted scores from database using user name. I have taken another text field to take user name and a button when I write "sarah" and click button it will return the score of sarah which is already inserted in database. But code is showing an error. I tried a lot but can not fix it.please help.here is my code

AS3 code:

```
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fetchscore);

function fetchscore(event:MouseEvent)
{
    var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

    var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://localhost/collectscore.php');

    phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;           
    phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);

    phpVars.systemCall = "processLogin";
    phpVars.cname = Name.text;

    phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);
}

function showResult(e:Event)
{
    //trace(phpVars.result);
    result_text.text = "" + e.target.data.systemResult;
}
```

fetchscore.php

```
<?php 
 include('connect.php');
 $username = $_POST['cname'];

if ($_POST['systemCall'] == "processLogin"){
$sqlqry = "SELECT * FROM scoreu WHERE username='$username'";//scoreu is my DBtable with two field user and score 
$query = mysqli_query($sqlqry);

$login_counter = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($login_counter > 0) {
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
if (mysqli_query($link), "SELECT score FROM scoreu WHERE user='$username'")) {
$findscore = $data['score'];
print 'result=$findscore';
}
}
} else {
 print 'result=The login details dont match names.';
}
}
?>
```

connect.php

```
<?php

// connect.php

$db_name = 'new';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_host = 'localhost';

$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die('Failed to connect to the server : '.mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: could you add the error message as well?

Comment: Error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.
 at Error$/throwError()
 at flash.net::URLVariables/decode()
 at flash.net::URLVariables()
 at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Comment: Seems like your PHP file collectscore.php has some issue and is throwing an error. Try to execute it in the browser and simulate with a hardcoded value for the variable $username, to see if it runs the entire scope.

Comment: use `phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT` and `result_text.text = "" + e.target.data` and see what is coming from PHP. BTW in PHP you're returning `result` but in AS3 you're trying to display `systemResult`.

Comment: i executed it in my browser there was a mistake i solved it but still the error is showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some "problems" in your code, lets start by the PHP code.

**PHP code :**

```
<?php

    // collectscore.php

    include('connect.php');

    $username = $_POST['cname'];
    if ($_POST['systemCall'] == "processLogin"){
        // you need only one request to get the score
        $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT score FROM scoreu WHERE user = '$username'");
        // you have to fetch the result into a php var
        if ($data =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $findscore = $data['score'];
            // you should use double quotes when passing vars into a string
            // otherwise, if you want use single quotes, you can write it : print 'result='.$findscore;
            print "result=$findscore";
        } else {
            print 'result=The login details dont match names.';
        }
    }

?>
```

**ActionScript code :**

```
function fetchscore(event:MouseEvent): void
{
    var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        phpVars.systemCall = "processLogin";
        phpVars.cname = cname.text; // name text field 

    var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://127.0.0.1/collectscore.php');
        phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        // you forgot to send your POST vars, for that, we use URLRequest.data
        phpFileRequest.data = phpVars;

    var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
        phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);
        phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);
}
function showResult(e:Event):void 
{
    // here the var should be the same as in the PHP script, result in this case : print "result=$findscore";
    trace(e.target.data.result);
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: thanku i am trying this solution ,when i give the input name "sarah" as3 is taking the name and sending it to php file but output is showing undefined..it was supposed to show the score but showing undefined..it can not find the score of "sarah" but i have stored user ->sarah  and score->10 in scoreu table

Comment: @Sarah5 Are you sure about the name of the var, it's `result` ?

Comment: @Sarah5 I am speaking about `result` in `print "result=$findscore";` and `trace(e.target.data.result);`.

Comment: @Sarah5 We will do easy, could you copy the code of your PHP script and the ActionScript one on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com) and put the link here ?

Comment: @Sarah5 Your code looks fine, so try to purge the cache of your browser and retry, and tell me.

Comment: @Sarah5 OK, you have a blank line before `<?php ` which caused the problem, remove it, and purge the cache and try again. It's working for me.

Comment: yes the cache is clear and i deleted the blank line anr run again but still saying undefined.. :( i know it must be any silly mistake but i am not getting that.. :( @Akmozo

Comment: @Sarah5 Last thing, try to change `print` by `echo` in the PHP code.

Comment: @Akomozo i had tried again and i have retrieved data from database..  .now your solution is working thank you again... :)